# show more than one People picker on a form

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, designer-workflow, people-picker

I am trying to use people picker to display Approver Manager and Requestor's manager on a custom form requestor will fill the form with the Requestors Manager and Approver Manager details but i am not able to retreive it using people picker.I am not sure what i am doing wrong can you please help??

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">Requestor's Manager: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <div id="manager" spclientpeoplepicker="true"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">Approval Manager: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <div id="amanager" spclientpeoplepicker="true"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

and here is the JS

```
var manager = [];
var amanager = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
LoadScripts();
initializePeoplePicker('manager', false, true, null, null);
initializePeoplePicker('amanager', false, true, null, null);
getSPOffset();
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId, allowMultipleValues, isPeopleOnly, GroupID, user) {
$.getScript("/TravelExpense/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js", function() {
    $.getScript("/TravelExpense/_layouts/15/clientforms.js", function() {
        $.getScript("/TravelExpense/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js", function() {
            $.getScript("/TravelExpense/_layouts/15/autofill.js", function() {
                $.getScript("/TravelExpense/_layouts/15/sp.js", function() {
                    $.getScript("/TravelExpense/_layouts/15/sp.core.js", function() {
                        var schema = {};
                        if(isPeopleOnly) {
                            schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User';
                        }
                        else {
                            schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
                        }
                        schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
                        schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
                        schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = allowMultipleValues;
                        schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
                        schema['Width'] = '280px';
                        if(GroupID != null) {
                            if (GroupID > 0) {  
                                schema['SharePointGroupID'] = GroupID  
                            }
                        }
                        SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, user, schema);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="microsoftajax.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="init.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.init.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
initializePeoplePicker('manager', false, true, null, null);
initializePeoplePicker('amanager', false, true, null, null);
});
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId, allowMultipleValues, isPeopleOnly, GroupID, user) {
    var schema = {};
    if(isPeopleOnly) {
        schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User';
    }
    else {
        schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    }
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = allowMultipleValues;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';
    if(GroupID != null) {
        if (GroupID > 0) {  
            schema['SharePointGroupID'] = GroupID  
        }
    }
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, user, schema);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">Requestor's Manager: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <div id="manager" spclientpeoplepicker="true"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">Approval Manager: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <div id="amanager" spclientpeoplepicker="true"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]